# How to determine the session type in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session

I want to change the `session` storage mode from `inproc` to some other third party session provider in my application. I have downloaded the standard `provider` written for it. I am using this provider in project and provided the server details in `web config` the session is working as expected. Problem I am facing is that even if I change the server details to any random ip, `session` code is still working. I am not able to determine if the session mode is getting changed internally after seeing invalid `ip` or something else is happening. I want to check in code which `sessionstate` mode my Application is using. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Mode
```

Which returns SessionStateMode enum value which is one of the following:

> - **InProc** mode, which stores session state in memory on the Web server.    This is the default.
> - **StateServer** mode, which stores session state in a separate process    called the ASP.NET state service. This ensures that session state is
>     preserved if the Web application is restarted and also makes session
>     state available to multiple Web servers in a Web farm.
> - **SQLServer** mode stores session state in a SQL Server database. This    ensures that session state is preserved if the Web application is
>     restarted and also makes session state available to multiple Web
>     servers in a Web farm.
> - **Custom** mode, which enables you to specify a custom storage provider.
> - **Off** mode, which disables session state.

[Source: MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. In my case it is showing mode as Custom which is correct. Is it possible to check the server and port details of the custom provider?